# Retrieve and display values from ResultSet in paticular order

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, servlets

I am retrieving records from database and display on JSP page, but the records are displayed in line by line but i want to display 3 records in one line and the fourth record should display in next line.

my jsp code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.* "%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eco", "root", "vicky");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from registration");
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
rs.afterLast();

while(rs.previous()){ %>
<p>  <%= rs.getString(2) %> </p>
<%} %>
</body>
</html>
```

database structure:

```
ID      username   email                  password
 1       vikas      vikas5@gmail.com        44
 2       Aravind    Aravind@gmail.com       12
 3       rakesh     rakesh@gmail.com        123
 4       chandra    chnadra@gmail.com       123
 5       shiva      chinthala@gmail.com     12345
 6       sai         sai@gmail.com          4321
 7       ravi         ravi@gmail.com        987654
```

my output:

```
ravi
sai
shiva
chandra
rakesh
Aravind
vikas
```

but i want output as:

```
ravi        sai      shiva  
chandra   rakesh     Aravind  
vikas
```

Comment: I don't know JSP that well, but since the strings are put into html, isn't it possible to give the `<p>` tag where the usernames are put into some CSS styling that does this?

Answer (score 0):

`select * from registration order by id desc` and use forward iteration. Also, I would prefer `rs.getString("username")` over `rs.getString(2)` because someone might add a column to the table in the future (here it would probably be better to limit the query to `username` as well). You haven't needed to use `Class.forName` to register your jdbc driver since Java 6 (JDBC 4.0). Finally, and to your question, keep a counter and add a line break every third row. Like,

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eco", 
        "root", "vicky");
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select username from registration order by id desc");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
int count = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    if (++count % 3 == 0) {
        %><br /><%
    }
    %><%= rs.getString("username"); %> <%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a table here.  The scriptlet below builds a three column wide HTML table, which is then populated in left to right and top to bottom order.

```
<table colspan="3">
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eco", "root", "vicky");
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM registration");
   ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

   int i = 0;
   while (rs.next()) {
       if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0) {%>
</tr>
<%     }
       if (i % 3 == 0) {%>
<tr>
<%     }%>
<td> <% rs.getString("username") %> </td>
   <% ++i; } %>
</tr>
</table>
```

As a side note, if you want to *order* the usernames coming from your MySQL table, then you should probably use an `ORDER BY` clause, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM registration ORDER BY username;
```

In general, there is no internal order to a SQL table, whose records are modeled after unordered sets.  The current ordering you are seeing could change at some point as new data gets added, so using an `ORDER BY` clause is a good way to have consistent output in your HTML page.